# How to connect javascript/angular.js game board to firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am working on an ongoing JavaScript/Angular.js game project.

This game has a game board where the player can click their character and move it to an adjacent square by clicking on that new square.

I am now trying to add a multiplayer feature to this game by having the changes on the board data saved and transmitted to any computer looking at the firebase application that I made for the game.

I have tried to do something simple like the following:

```
$scope.$watch("board", updateDatabase, true);

  function updateDatabase(){
      myFirebaseRef.set($scope.board);
  }
```

This does update an array of arrays in the database that represents the board's square "cell" objects well. However, it breaks some other functionality in the code like an AI pathfinding check for a wall using an isWall attribute. (I am not sure why this is.)

What would you recommend to fix the issue and be able to grab the data back so that other computers can see the change to the firebase app automatically?

I put the files on plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/80UEpIoXtriDMLfdsgN9?p=streamer&s=Hga74ZPLuT0rZ0h3
(The main file is script.js)

Thank you for your time and have a great day!

-Matt S.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Angularfire" is a library that lets you handle information between AngularJS and Firebase in a easier way.

Go to their quick start page and you will get a grasp of it in 5 ~ 10 minutes. Is pretty awesome!

This is the link: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html